# C3193: __clrcall requires /clr or /ZW command line option on boost header

Tags: c++, boost, clr

I'm upgrading my boost library from 1.67 to 1.71, but once I build my C++ project I get the following error C3193 on the `is_function_cxx_11.hpp` 102 row which is

> struct is_function : public true_type {};

But I can't even turn on /clr on my project because it has a lot of dependencies as unmanaged code with other projects.

Is there any workaround this problem.? Or I'm supposed to just stay on the 1.67 v at this point?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] and edit it into the question (I think the only way to achieve that would be to `#define __CLR_VER` before including boost). But why do you define `__CLR_VER`?

Answer (score -1):

I added the below in my code before including boost/filesystem..

```
#ifdef __CLR_VER
#undef __CLR_VER
#endif
```

I don't understand this much but I think it just invoked the clr for that particular code file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).